# Permission Error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'traccert/tesseract.exe' while run our flask application

Tags: python, heroku, tesseract

When I run the application on local host, its working fine, but when I run the application on heroku and try to convert the image to text its show an error. You may check the image below.

This is path to tesseract:
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'traccert/tesseract.exe'

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXvU.png): [click here to see the image of an error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWXvU.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to execute a `.exe` file, which is only runnable on the Windows operating system. [Heroku's platform is Linux-based](https://www.heroku.com/dynos/build), which means you won't be able to run that `.exe` file.

If you're willing to do some work, you might be able to get the `.exe` file running by building a [custom Heroku Buildpack](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) that includes [wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine), but this depends on a lot of variables: what libraries your Windows executable relies on, etc.

Comment: Work fine by making *custom Heroku Buildpack*